# How to express it into set builder method?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$\left\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{10},\frac{4}{28},\frac{8}{82},\frac{16}{244},\frac{32}{730}\right\}$$

Above is a set  which I have to express into set builder method .

So, I have divided into two parts:

For the numerator, I got the condition $p=2^x$ ,$0\le x \le 5$

For the denominator $q=3^n+1$, $1\le n \le 6$

I can't write it in set builder form. Can anyone help me to write the set in builder form?

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, the numerators are the powers of $2$, whereas the denominators are generated by the linear recurrence relation $x_0=4;x_n=3x_{n-1}-2.$ The latter has the closed form $x_n=A3^n+B.$ Consequently, the general term to build the required set is $\displaystyle\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}+1},$ where $n=0,1,2,3,4,5.$ Equivalently: $\displaystyle\frac{2^{n-1}}{3^n+1},$ where $n=1,2,3,4,5,6.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:
$$\left\{ \frac{2^{n}}{3^{n+1}+1}\mid0\leq n\leq5\right\}$$
or more precize:
$$\left\{ \frac{2^{n}}{3^{n+1}+1}\mid0\leq n\leq5\tag{ },n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\} $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You have written correctly. Now, just notice that for each term in the set, $n=x+1$. So, substitute this value and the set becomes
$$\left\{y:\ y=\frac{2^x}{3^{x+1}+1},\ 0\leq x\leq 5,\ x\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

Or simply,
$$\left\{\frac{2^x}{3^{x+1}+1}:\ 0\leq x\leq 5,\ x\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

[If you're unfamiliar $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ means $x$ is an integer.]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much 